# Choosing website architecture/logic/structure for frontend and how to implement it

Tags: php, html, web, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

What is the "best" (your opinion) and the most common way to structure the frontend architecture for websites that are very interactive and mostly "feel" like an app? What loads the quickest, what is the most efficient, what is the easiest to maintain?

**Example**

The website consists of the following pages:

- Homepage
- Write Post
- Post Timeline
- Explore (Posts & Users)
- and some legal pages like terms...

I use the same header (with navbar) and footer on every page but have some page-specific scripts embedded.

Should I create a `.php` file for every page and import header and footer or should I make the user stay on the same file while navigating and dynamically change the content of the main page to the desired view? Would there be better ways to solve this?

I know that there might not be enough detail to answer the question but maybe It helps me an other users to orientate themselves. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you looking for? The BEST way or the MOST COMMON way to do it? Don't assume these 2 are the same :-(

Comment: @C.B. For both. Yes that might be true so the questions can be answered seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit generic, but maybe you can first take a look at:
- MVC architecture 
- Templating (Twig ?... - question tagged as php)
- Routing (SEO-friendly URLs and execution of a controller action on each request)
- Javascript and Ajax for dom modification on the fly

For one page web applications, you may also look at JS frameworks like Angular, Embed, Vue...